# Why does reactive extensions stop calling the subscriber after an exception is thrown when using Where or OfType operators?

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Test1 passes. Why do Test2 and Test3 fail? I'm using .NET 4.0 and Rx 2.0.

```cs
[TestClass]
public class RxQuestion
{
   private Subject<string> sequence;
   [TestInitialize] public void Intialize() { sequence = new Subject<string>(); }
   [TestMethod] public void Test1() { Test(sequence); }
   [TestMethod] public void Test2() { Test(sequence.Where(s => true)); }
   [TestMethod] public void Test3() { Test(sequence.OfType<string>()); }
   private void Test(IObservable<string> observable)
   {
      var observed = string.Empty;
      observable.Subscribe(s => { observed = s; if (s == "a") throw new Exception(); });
      try { sequence.OnNext("a"); } catch { }
      sequence.OnNext("b");
      Assert.AreEqual("b", observed);
   }
}
```

Comment: Ah, upon a reread, I notice I misinterpreted what was happening here...my answer does not apply to this situation per se, so I'll remove it and have a think. First question, have you tried stepping through the tests to see what is happening?

Comment: Yes, Test1 passes. Test2 and Test3 behave the same. When sequence.OnNext("b") executes, the observer is never called.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The real question to me is why does Test1 pass? To me it looks like the `Subject<T>` type is not playing by the same rules as all the other implementations of `IObservable<T>`.

On deeper inspection (well reflection really), you can pull apart the `Subject<T>` type in DotPeek/Reflector and see that when an `OnNext(T)` call is made, it is delegated directly to its `_observer` instance. Prior to any subscriptions this is just a NullObject/NopObserver. After a subscription is made (in general) the observer is an `Observer<T>` implementation. This implementation is really a composite pattern implementation of the `IObserver<T>` interface, that just calls `OnNext(T)` for each of its instances.

Furthermore, if we consider that we are using the extension method of Subscribe that just takes an OnNext handler, we now know that our real implmentation of the the `IObserver<T>` is an `AnonymousObserver<T>`. Opening this up we see that any call to `OnNext(T)` is largely unprotected.

Now let us compare this to the `IObservable<T>` implementations from the `Where` or `Cast` operators. Both of these extension methods will return you an `IObservable<T>` implementation that extends the `Producer<T>` class. When subscriptions are made to one of these observable sequences, the subscribing observer is wrapped by a `SafeObserver<T>` implementation. **This is the key difference**.

If we look into this implementation, we see that for our code path, the anon observer we have will have its MakeSafe method called. This now wraps any call to OnNext with a try/finally.

```
public void OnNext(T value)
{
    if(this.isStopped!=0)
        return;
    bool flag = true;
    try
    {
        this._onNext(value);
        flag=true;        //Flag only set if OnNext doesn't throw!!
    }
    finally
    {
        if(!flag)
            this._disposable.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Note that once we have a safe observer as per above, if any `OnNext` handler throws, then the `flag` will not get set to true and the `_disposable` instance is disposed. In this case the `_disposable` instance represents the subscription.

So there is your explanation as to why the raw `Subject` passes the test and where the seemingly innocuous operators cause a change in behavior.

As to why `Subject<T>` does not behave like this by default, I imagine this is due to the performance improvements that were made in the 2.0 release. I get the feeling that subjects are tuned for raw performance and take the assumption that if you are brave enough to be using them, then you know what you are doing (i.e. not throwing in your `OnNext` handlers!). I base this assumption that they also removed the concurrency safety from subjects by default and you have to turn it on with the `Synchronize()` extension method, maybe they also thought all of those extra try/finally calls should only be paid for if you opt in. One way of opting in to these safety features is to do what you have done above `Where(_=>true)` or more commonly `AsObservable()`.

Comment: +1 - this is exactly the line of investigation I was going to take had I access to my laptop this weekend. :)

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I was saying but with lots of details. Good explanation.

Comment: Excellent answer! Thank you very much for taking the time to provide so much detail.

Comment: It is a very good question too! This one really made me think and challenge some of my assumptions about how Rx should/did work. It also sparked some good debate (specifically with Timothy) around the subtleties of Errors/Exceptions in Rx

Answer (score 2):

By definition, an `IObservable<T>` should **not** emit any more notifications after either an `OnError` or an `OnCompleted`. So when you call `sequence.OnNext("b");` you are actually violating the implicit contract an `IObservable<T>` is supposed to adhere to.

The reason `Where` and `OfType` are behaving this way is because they are (appropriately) ignoring any notifications after the `OnError` you are generating.

Comment: OnError/OnCompleted are never called in the code above. Are you saying that internally Rx is called OnError automatically when an exception is thrown?

Comment: When you call `sequence.OnNext("a");` the `ISubject<T>` is internally notifying your subscriber function, which throws an exception. Before this exception reaches your `try-catch` block, the `Where` or `OfType` get their hands on it. They decide internally to never forward any more notifications because they've seen an `OnError` notification. The reason `Test1` succeeds is because the `ISubject<T>` is apparently *not* performing this reasoning.

Comment: I would suggest using `IObservable<T>.Materialize()` to get a better idea of exactly what notifications are being passed around here...

Comment: One other thing I think might be confusing you: when you throw an exception, that very much *is* like calling `OnError`.

Comment: @Robin: 'OnError' is your subscription to error event, if you wanna perform custom action. Error is thrown anyway and subscription subsequently is canceled. In your case, you should use 'OnError' to re-subscribe to IObservable.

Comment: In this case, it is not like calling OnError. A subscriber can not alter the behavior of a sequence, i.e. a Subscriber can not force an OnNext call to magically become an OnError call. This would kind-of make the communication two way. A Select operator can cause an error to become an OnError, but this is because the output is a different sequence, it is not altering the original sequence.

Comment: What you are seeing here is a very simple case of the observer pattern  in the case of the Subject, and a safe implementation in the other two cases.

Comment: @Lee Campbell "a Subscriber can not force an OnNext call to magically become an OnError call" - and yet that's exactly what's happening, because of the details of the Subject class that you outlined in your answer.  The tests 2 and 3 are simple proof of this.

Comment: No, OnError is not called. As the Subject is not "safe" it behaves 'badly' and doesn't disconnect the naughty observer that is throwing in its OnNext callback. ie. The handler is affecting the behavior of the subject but not the actual data in the sequence. Subtle difference between the two.

Comment: I can understand your confusion, but I dont know how you arrived at believing that the Where and Cast operators see an OnError. They actually are catching an exception when they delegate a call to their observers. Don't confuse throwing exceptions with "erroring a sequence", they are different things.